Worksheet associated with parameter different in Calling routine and in Called routine
I've got a routine (one of many) which calls a common paste routine (to avoid having to code the parameters in a .PasteSpecial (I know it's slower, but easier to avoid coding errors and aborted test runs working with split lines) when I need to copy a range from one location to another, sometimes to different sheets.
What I've finally traced is that a calling routine sends a Source and Target range to the common paste routine (pasteRange).  I have confirmed that the calling ranges sent ARE correctly defined (including Worksheet Name).  However, when it enters pasteRange, before executing any statements, the range parameters no longer have a valid sheet-associated worksheet range.  This does NOT always happen - as I said, it just seems to happens.  99% of the time it works perfectly.  Failure doesn't depend on source file (they work fine most of the time, fail others).
I've been over the variable definitions, range assignments, etc, and I cannot see anything different from the calls which work and those which fail.
Calling routing code
' Copy the Header block to an archive location to avoid corruption during column processing
cells(1, 1).Select
rawHeader = cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
Call colorRange(Range(cells(1, 1), cells(rawHeader, 9999).End(xlToLeft).Offset(-2, 0)), rngHOLDBanner, 37, xlAutomatic, 0)
Call pasteRange(Range(cells(1, 1), cells(rawHeader, 9999).End(xlToLeft).Offset(-2, 0)), rngHOLDBanner, "A")
Call defRange("holdRAWBanner", Range(rngHOLDBanner, rngHOLDBanner.Offset(rawHeader - 1.9999).End(xlToLeft).Offset(-2, 0)), shtRAW)

Here is debug watch image.  Green box is around calling routine range values at time of call to pasteRange.;

Here is the code for the pasteRange subroutine;
    '**              Optional   pTSheet     String       Target Sheet (if different than Source).
'**                                                  BLANK if named range or Source & Target are in same sheet
'**
'** Pastes copied range to the pTarget cell (range).  pOption can contain one or more of the options
'*************************************************************************************
Sub pasteRange(Optional pSource As Range = Nothing, _
               Optional pTarget As Range = Nothing, _
               Optional pOptions As String = "", _
               Optional pSSheet As String = "", _
               Optional pTSheet As String = "")
    
' If pSource is NULL, then past wll be of current Copy buffer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    pOptions = UCase(pOptions)
    If (Not pSource Is Nothing) Then
        If (pSSheet = "") Then

and, here is the debug watch image immediately after entering the pasteRange routine.

In the pasteRange routine, the pSource range is exactly what was sent to it.  However, you can see that pTarget is messed up.  It's got "not defined" as the range, and is using the last sheet name in the workbook as the assigned range worksheet.  If I run through the routine, it actually uses the last sheet in the workbook as the target sheet, placing the paste in the correct target range, but the incorrect sheet.  You can see in the watch information that the calling routine range definitions are still correct.
What could I have done to cause this?
NOTE: I did NOT try changing the source and target parameter ranges this time - I wanted to preserve (and resolve the darned thing!) as this error doesn't always occur.  In the past, simply stoping this run and rerunning using the same input file will usually run successfully with no issues.

pTarget.range is not an expression.
pTarget.address is something that will evaluate.

Well, that's embarrassing :(  I don't remember using .Range at anytime in the past.  Stupid brain (mine).  Updated Watch attached

That at least shows that the range was passed correctly, but doesn't explain why the Worksheet.Name is incorrect (XRef instead of the RawData that was passed).
PS: Posting this as an answer as commenting won't allow uploading a corrected Watch image.
